# Problems when handling orientation changes

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-orientation, android-2.2-froyo

I need to handle orientation changes in my Android application. For this purpose I decided to use `OrientationEventListener` convenience class. But his callback method is given somewhat strange behavior.

My application starts in the portrait mode and then eventually switches to the lanscape one. I have some custom code executing in the callback `onOrientationChanged` method that provides some additional UI handling logic - it has a few calls to `findViewById`.
What is strange is that when switching back from landscape to portrait mode `onOrientationChanged` callback is called twice, and what's even worse - the second call is dealing with **bad** `Context` - `findViewById` method starts returning `null`. These calls are made right from the *MainThread*

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listener = new OrientationListener();
}

    @Override
protected void onResume() {     
    super.onResume();
    // enabling listening
    listener.enable();
}
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // disabling listening
    listener.disable();
}
```

I've replicated the same behavior with a dummy `Activity` without any logic except for one that deals with orientation hadling.
I initiate orientation switch from the Android 2.2 emulator by pressing *Ctrl+F11*
What could be wrong?

Upd:
Inner class that implements `OrientationEventListener`

```
private class OrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {
    public OrientationL() {
        super(getBaseContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

        toString();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: please post your onOrientationChanged code too

Comment: Have you tried this when testing on a real phone? I had some issues with orientation changes that only happened when testing on an emulator. It had something to do with the emulator fakes the screen orientation change - I also had an issue with it recreating the app twice.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have access to real phone for now

Comment: I wrote a [post](http://wp.me/pU69m-2L) that describes the emulator bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a documented bug in the emulator ONLY.  A real device will not exhibit this double-lifecycle-events behavior.  I had the same issue a while ago and it disappears on a real device.

I would suggest ignoring the problem if you can by only testing orientation changes in one direction until you get your hands on a physical phone.  Otherwise you might be able to "skip" the second set of lifecycle calls by keeping a static boolean around indicating you've already gone through the first set.

See [this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2423) for more info.

Comment: had some trouble on motorola xoom , onCreate is called twice a row too 
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3922257

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using onConfigurationChanged?

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
 if(newConfig.equals(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)…
```

Comment: I get the same problem with `findViewById` method. It's odd but it seems that declarative layout specified in `.xml` file haven't rendered yet.

Comment: anyway onConfigurationChanged seems to be better solution when compared with OrientationEventListener callback subscription

Answer (score 1):

Add **android:configChanges="orientation"** in manifest file in activity tag like

`<activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="orientation" 
    android:name=".com.androidpeople">`